# Аналог Visual Assist в QT Creator

Tags: c++, c, qt

Недавно начал работу в среде qt Creator. После C++ Builder + CN Wizards и Visual Studio + Visual Assist, заинтересовался вопросом - существуют ли какие-то аналоги для QT Creator?
C уважением, maxspb.

Comment: Проще так или иначе прикрепить Qt и Visual Assist к Visual Studio, чем Visual Assist к Qt Creator.

Comment: А собственно каких фич Visual Assist не хватает?